# Magisk module to modify /system folder

Tags: android, adb, rom

can anyone advise on a Magisk module that would allow me to modify the /system folder which by default is read-only.

Comment: Just remount system to r/w. That is one command and thus so simple that no module is needed.

Comment: so can i just do it w/ adb? like adb remount? thats it?